Bootstrap.yaml is deprecated and should i use application.yaml?
With Spring Cloud Vault 3.0 and Spring Boot 2.4, the bootstrap context initialization (bootstrap.yml, bootstrap.properties) click here for official documentation
My application pod is crushing with bootstrap.yaml
should I modify it to application.yaml, is it works?
We are upgraded Springboot 3.3.1 from 2.3.7
because of bootstrap.yaml is not picking the AWS secrets, my application pod is crushing and not able to start.
my bootstrap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.name" . }}
  labels: {{ include "app.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  bootstrap.yaml: >-
    aws:
      secretsmanager:
        prefix: /secret
        defaultContext: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
        profileSeparator: _
        failFast: true
        name: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}_{{ template "app.name" . }}"
        enabled: true
    cloud:
      aws:
        region:
          static: {{ .Values.region }}

my deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.name" . }}
  labels: {{ include "app.labels" . | indent 4 }}
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
{{- if not .Values.hpa.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
{{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels: {{ include "app.selector" . | indent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: {{ include "app.selector" . | indent 8 }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "app.name" . }}
      securityContext:
      {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      initContainers:
      - name: generate-keystore
        image: {{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - >
          openssl pkcs12 -export -name cert -in /cert/tls.crt -inkey /cert/tls.key -nodes -out /keystore/keystore.p12 -passout pass:password;
{{- if .Values.mTLS }}
          keytool -importcert -file /cert/ca.crt -alias CAcert -keystore /keystore/truststore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -noprompt -storepass password;
{{- end }}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /keystore
          name: keystore
        - mountPath: /cert
          name: cert
{{- if or .Values.apm.elastic.enabled .Values.apm.otel.enabled }}
      - name: apm-attach
        image: {{ .Values.apm.image.name }}:{{ .Values.apm.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
          - name: apm
            mountPath: apm
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - "mkdir -p /apm/elastic-apm/ /apm/otel && cp /elastic-apm-agent.jar /apm/elastic-apm/ && cp /aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar /apm/otel "
{{- end }}
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.name }}
        image: {{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: service
            name: service
        readinessProbe: {{- toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | nindent 10 }}
        livenessProbe: {{- toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | nindent 10 }}
        securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 10 }}
        env:
        - name: ENVIRONMENT
          value: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
        - name: ENV
          value: {{ .Release.Namespace }}

#spring boot variables
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: "8080"
        - name: SERVER_SSL_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE
          value: /keystore/keystore.p12
        - name: SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD
          value: "password"
        - name: SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE
          value: "PKCS12"
        - name: SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH
          value: "/{{ .Values.name }}"
{{- if .Values.mTLS }}
        - name: SERVER_SSL_TRUST_STORE
          value: /keystore/truststore.p12
        - name: SERVER_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: SERVER_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE
          value: PKCS12
{{- end }}
        - name: MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT
          value: "8888"
        - name: MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_BASE_PATH
          value: "/"
        - name: MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_PATH-MAPPING_HEALTH
          value: health
        - name: MANAGEMENT_SERVER_SSL_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        - name: MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_EXPOSURE_INCLUDE
          value: "*"
        - name: MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_SHUTDOWN_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        - name: MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_HEALTH_SHOW_DETAILS
          value: ALWAYS
        - name: SPRING_BOOTSTRAP_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.location=/bootstrap/
        - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
          value: regional 
#end spring boot
#elastic apm
{{- if .Values.apm.elastic.enabled }}
        - name: ELASTIC_APM_JAVA_OPTS
          value: >
            -Delastic.apm.server_urls={{ .Values.apm.elastic.server }}
            -Delastic.apm.application_packages=org.iata.timatic
            -Delastic.apm.service_name={{ .Values.name }}
            -Delastic.apm.service_version={{ .Values.image.tag }}
            -Delastic.apm.environment={{ .Values.environment }}
            -Delastic.apm.enable_log_correlation=true
            -javaagent:/apm/elastic-apm/elastic-apm-agent.jar
            {{.Values.apm.elastic.config}}
{{- else if .Values.apm.otel.enabled }}
        - name: OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES
          value: service.name={{ .Values.name }}-{{ .Release.Namespace }},service.namespace={{ .Release.Namespace }},environment={{ .Release.Namespace }}
        - name: OTEL_APM_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -javaagent:/apm/otel/aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar
        - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
          value: "http://aws-otel-opentelemetry-collector.aws-otel:4317"
        - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT
          value: "http://aws-otel-opentelemetry-collector.aws-otel:4317"
  {{-  range $key, $value := .Values.apm.otel.envs }}
        - name: {{ $key }}
          value: {{ $value }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
#java opts
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.javaOpts }}
        - name: {{ printf "%s_JAVA_OPTS" $key | upper }}
          value: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
#iterate through common envs
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.envs }}
        - name: {{ $key }}
          value: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end }}
        resources: {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 10 }}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /keystore
          name: keystore
        - mountPath: /bootstrap
          name: bootstrap
#apm mounts
{{- if or .Values.apm.elastic.enabled .Values.apm.otel.enabled }}
        - name: apm
          mountPath: /apm
{{- end }}
      volumes:
      - name: keystore
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: cert
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: {{ template "app.name" . }}-app-cert
      - name: bootstrap
        configMap:
          name: {{ template  "app.name" . }}
{{- if or .Values.apm.elastic.enabled .Values.apm.otel.enabled }}
      - name: apm
        emptyDir: {}
{{- end }}

What are the changes I need to do?

can anyone pls check my question please
